# Как добавить класс к таблице

Tags: javascript

Дана таблица:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="c">Текст</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как можно добавить уже существующий класс к этой таблице при загрузке страницы без использования jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var tab = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    tab[0].setAttribute('class', 'qwerty');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем tab[0].setAttribute('class', 'qwerty');
если можно проще tab[0].className = 'qwerty'